# Python Microservice Structure

Tags: python-3.x, frameworks, microservices

I want to create a microservice application on Python. Can anyone help me the standard folder structure and the standard libraries used. An example with a two microservice would be helpful to understand.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no folder structure for microservices. Every service can have a different structure with different intent and still work as long as the contracts between 2 or more services are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [django project skeleton](https://github.com/Mischback/django-project-skeleton) - [structure in the description](https://github.com/Mischback/django-project-skeleton/blob/development/doc/source/structure.rst) or the [PyMS](https://github.com/python-microservices/pyms) library and an [example application](https://github.com/python-microservices/microservices-scaffold) using it.
It's not perfect but at first glance you can learn something.
In general, you can take any large open source project that you like and see its structure. ;)